# Subspace of dual vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> Let $V^{*}:= \mathcal{L}(V,K)$. Let $S^{\circ} := \{f \in V^{*}\mid S
>  \subseteq \ker (f)\}$. If $\dim(V) = n$, $S$ a subspace of $V$ with 
>   $\dim(S) = r$, show that $\dim S^{\circ} = \dim V - \dim S$

**My attempt:**

Let $(s_1,\dots s_r)$ be a basis of $S$. Expand this basis to a basis of $V$: $(s_1, \dots, s_r, v_{r+1}, \dots, v_n)$. It is sufficient to prove that $(v_{r+1}^{*}, \dots v_n^{*})$ (where $v_i^{*}$ is the functional $V \to K$ that maps a vector to its $i'th$ coordinate relative to the listed basis of $V$) is a basis of $S^{\circ}$

We have to show two things, linear independency and span

For linear independency,

suppose $0 = \sum \alpha_i v_i^{*}$. Evaluating this in the vectors $v_{r+1}, \dots, v_n$ yields subsequently $\alpha_{r+1} = 0, \dots \alpha_n = 0$

Hence, the set is linear independent.

I am struggling however with proving that the set also spans $S^{\circ}$. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, now:
if $f\in S^\circ$ and $x=\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_is_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n-r}y_iv_{i+r}\in V$, then by linearlity $$f(x)=f(\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_is_i)+f(\sum_{i=1}^{n-r}y_iv_{i+r})=\sum_{i=1}^{n-r}y_if(v_{i+r})=\sum_{i=1}^{n-r}f(v_{i+r})v^*_{i+r}(x)$$
Thus $f\in span\{v^*_{r+1},\dots,v^*_n\}$.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path, but there's an easier proof.

Consider the linear map
$$
\varphi\colon V^*\to K^r
\qquad
\varphi(\xi)=\bigl(\xi(s_1),\dots,\xi(s_r)\bigr)
$$
which is surjective and has kernel precisely $S^0$.

Surjectivity follows from considering that $\varphi(s_i^*)$ is the $i$-th coordinate vector (for $i=1,2,\dots,r$). Moreover $\varphi(\xi)=0$ if and only if $\xi(s_i)=0$ for $i=1,2,\dots,r$, that is, if and only if $\xi(S)=\{0\}$.

Now apply the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Indeed, a fine solution! I had already marked an answer but this is equally good. Thanks!